# What is the best way to create a slideshow in iphoto across multiple events?

Tags: photos.app, slideshow

I want to put together a slideshow but i want to use pictures across multiple events.  I see you can click on Slideshow on a particular event.  Do I have to copy these picture all into a new "event" just to do a slideshow on it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even easier: Make an Album of the photos you want to use in the Slideshow, and base it on that. This has a couple of advantages:

1. It simply references the photos in the Events, and uses no ezra disk space, while keeping your Events intact
2. You can sort the photos manually, into any order you like, which you can't do with Events.

To make a new Album: select a couple of the pics and go Command-n; then drag the rest of the photos to that

Or, shift-command-n to make a new empty album

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous post, once you've created your album and it shows in your source list on the left-hand side, you would then select the album for which you want to create the slideshow and click on the Create button.